# Get data from the html website using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How could I get the "New Cases" number from the website(https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#cases_casesper100klast7days) using python?

Here is my code at this time:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request

res = urllib.request.urlopen('https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data- 
tracker/#cases_casesper100klast7days')
output = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(output, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all(class_='d-flex container-fluid'):
    item = tag.find('div',class_='card-recent')
    print(item)
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the current code?

Comment: the main problem: the `+20,473 New Cases` is occur after few seconds

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded dynamically via sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=US_MAP_DATA
```

You can get the "new cases" (as well as other data) from there as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request

res = urllib.request.urlopen(
    "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=US_MAP_DATA"
)
output = res.read()

data = json.loads(output)

print(data["US_MAP_DATA"][-1]["us_trend_new_case"])
```

Output:

```
20473
```

You can also `print(data)` to see all the data, which is available in a dictionary (`dict`) format.

---

A simpler approach would be to use the `requests` module instead of `urlib` which would simplify your code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData?id=US_MAP_DATA"
).json()
print(response["US_MAP_DATA"][-1]["us_trend_new_case"])
```